# Arranging elementes as pairs with Bootstrap (responsive)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

On my bootstrap site, I have 6 pics in a row (desktop view):

```
|  Ø  Ø  Ø  Ø  Ø  Ø   |
```

But when I open the site with a tablet or phone, I want to group those pics in pairs - centered in the middle:

```
|        Ø  Ø         |
|        Ø  Ø         |
|        Ø  Ø         |
```

Instead, the result is always like this:

```
|Ø                    |
|Ø                    |
|Ø                    |
|Ø                    |
|Ø                    |
|Ø                    |
```

How do I have to modify the classes to properly arrange the items?

**UPDATE**

I grouped the elements as 3 pairs. When I switch to desktop mode, everything is fine except when I view the site on tablet or phone.

Tablet

```
| Ø  Ø   Ø  Ø         |
| Ø  Ø                |
```

Phone

```
| Ø  Ø                |
| Ø  Ø                |
| Ø  Ø                |
```

This is the code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span4">
      <div class="row-fluid text">
          <div class="span6">
            <p><img src="img/icon.png"></p>
          </div>
          <div class="span6">
            <p><img src="img/icon.png"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="span4">
      <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span6">
            <p><img src="img/icon.png"></p>
          </div>
          <div class="span6">
            <p><img src="img/icon.png"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
  </div> <div class="span4">
      <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span6">
            <p><img src="img/icon.png"></p>
          </div>
          <div class="span6">
           <p><img src="img/icon.png"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Take a look at this quick fiddle i made [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9GjSU/)

```
<div class="span-1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x100" alt=""></div>
<div class="span-2"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x100" alt=""></div>
<div class="span-3"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x100" alt=""></div>
<div class="span-4"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x100" alt=""></div>
<div class="span-5"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x100" alt=""></div>
<div class="span-6"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x100" alt=""></div>
```

> Above is simular layout to  yours
>
> Tiny bit of CSS

```
div[class^="span-"] {
    width:49%; // Each image parent 49% (1% left for margin)
    float:left; // Float them all left so we can fit 2 on each line
    margin:0 .5%; // Little bit of margin for visibility 
}

div[class^="span-"]:nth-child(odd){
    text-align:right; // For every odd element align it right ( for even default is left anyway)
}
```

> Makes this

And that's all there is to it. you come across some conflict in bootstrap but you should be able to figure that out seeing as there isn't a lot that can be over-ridden.

And by the way you cant build a website with just classes, even in bootstrap you have to use `CSS` too

[image]

Comment: You, sir, deserve my honor. Thank you! (Of course, I can't just build a website using only pre-defined classes, but I  wan't to avoid doing the same task twice)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to specify for each resolution the sytle of those pics in the bootstrap-responsive.css file. In order for them to appear as you want.

Did you include the responsive stylesheet that comes with bootstrap? Are you using the proper classes like "span12", "span2" etc?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that in the bootstrap responsive css, all the spans become 100% width when the viewport switches to tablet or phone. Instead of using a span6 class, you just need to create a new class and set width to something close to 50% (depending on the margins you want) and set float left